# How do I make CSS and JS not submit cookie with each request?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, asp.net-4.0

CSS and JS file carry cookies with individual request. Is there any trick to disable carrying cookies and request and response header with individual headers? There shouldn't be any need to carry these for JS and CSS files.

I am using IIS 7 and Asp.Net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a different domain, ie typically websites will setup `static.yourwebsite.com`.

As long as the cookies domain is set to only the original domain, it wont be sent to `static.bla.com`

The `static.bla.com` of course can be pointing to the same site/server, but for the browser, its a different domain.

Comment: is not only the domain, you need to setup also the iis to not use cookies.